# Is this a different accent than Tokyo's?

Tags: orthography, dialects, spoken-language

A friend of mine wrote：

> 誘えていないんだ。

But aparently it should be written as:

> 誘いていないんか。

I think this is not a typo because he wrote two different sentences, both with `え` instead of `い`. Is this wrong or just a local difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is either wrong or dialectal about 「[誘]{さそ}えていないんだ。」.  It sounds 100% natural and it would be said all over the country.

It is your 「誘**い**ていないんか。」 that is incorrect.  There is no such conjugation as 「誘いて」 in standard Japanese.  The correct form is 「誘って」 for the plain and 「誘えて」 for the potential.

> 「[誘]{さそ}えていないんだ。」 means:
>
> "(You) have not been able to invite (someone)."

Comment: Yes.... I have a friend in Yamanashi, and I am living in Tokyo and I can not find any "difference" between us. If we have dialects, I think they would begin from around western part of Shizuoka prefecture to the further west.

Comment: I doubted because google give me a wrong translation, I don't trust that much in google translator but I wanted to be sure. Thanks!